# How can I run 2 methods synchronously while one of them contains Sleep thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to programming and I didnt learn anything that kind since didnt had any need in that.
Now I successfully created discord server bot (Discord = messanger platform commonly used between teens).
and everything was fine until I had to create method in which I am waiting few minutes using Thread.Sleep :

```
//inside the main method of recieving message this code happening and this line includes an "if" statement which if true will start the timer

if (.......) {
timeInMillieseconds = timeInMinutes * 60000;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeInMillieseconds);
//after the program done waiting it will do the code I assigned here
}
```

The only problem is that I need the rest of the program to keep running while this specific line to wait.
It does make sense since when I am calling for this method my Discord bot will stop recieving messages duo to the sleep thread, and I want the bot to keep recieving messages although this specific method is waiting.
I thought maybe if I will create another method it will run synchronously but wasnt sure about how to do it (because I am pretty sure there is something I need to add in order for this to work synchronously)

I am terrible at explanations so I hope that I was clear, if I wasnt please let me know how can I help you helping me.

P.s : if this is helping somehow I am writing this code in C#.

best regards,
Jake.

Comment: `Task.Run` would be where I would suggest you start.

Comment: [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0) as mjwills noted

Comment: I think when you say "syncronously" you actually mean "asyncronously".. Anyway, perhaps consider *not* sending a thread to sleep for two minutes, `await Task.Delay(120000)` instead

Comment: "untill I had to create method in which I am waiting few minutes using Thread.Sleep". What are you actually trying to accomplish by having a thread sleep? Usually in these kind of chat bots I would assume the goal is to run some code at a later time. There are way better options for this then `Thread.Sleep` (a good example would be the `Timer` class)

Comment: this is a common multithreading problem covered by mainly all general multi threading tutorials. You should start reading one of those tutorials to get a common sense of multithrading and messaging.

Comment: Winforms? Wpf? console?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** :
I used `Timer Class` to solve this issue.
I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0) to build the timer class correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You should start new threads - in this case, two threads and give them their todo methods, so if the method contains sleep only the current thread doing this sleep will stop and the other one keeps doing its job.

Comment: I disagree. Newbies should avoid multithreaded programming where possible

Comment: The question was "How can I run 2 methods synchronously while one of them contains Sleep thread?" - so you can't run synchronously without threads, so I just answered the question - you can disagree with him.

Comment: Yes, it's a reasonable point. I would though urge caution to the effect that when a newbie asks something that could get them into trouble, they should perhaps be steered back towards a course of action that will be less problematic.